# Is it possible to write code that can switch between HPX and C++1x thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, hpx

Since the API is fairly similar between `hpx` and `#include<thread>` is it possible to have the same code be able to run `hpx` or `#include<thread>`?

Since boost is a requirement of `hpx`, my use case here is there are systems that aren't allowed boost and some that are, I want the same code to run on both, but use `hpx` if possible.

Assuming I'm only using features that are in both hpx and thread, Is there an example of doing this? Would I even be able to via `#ifdef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API of both libraries is exactly the same, you can use a type alias that gets compiled conditionally:

```
#if defined(USE_HPX_THREADS)

#include <hpx/thread.hpp>

namespace my_library
{
    using my_thread = hpx::thread;
}

#elif defined(USE_STD_THREADS)

#include <thread>

namespace my_library
{
    using my_thread = std::thread;
}

#endif
```

Alternatively, if the APIs differ, you can create your own homogeneous interface, with different implementations depending on a preprocessor definition:

```
class my_thread 
{
private:
    // "Conditional type alias" like the example above.
    my_thread_handle _thread;

public:
    void join();
};

#if defined(USE_HPX_THREADS)

void my_thread::join()
{
    _thread.hpx_join();
}

#elif defined(USE_STD_THREADS)

void my_thread::join()
{
    _thread.std_join();
}

#endif
```

It could be a good idea to separate the implementations in different files. Check out libraries like SFML [for a real-world example](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/src/SFML/Network) *(Unix and Win32 folders)*.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs of `std::thread` and `hpx::thread` are completely identical, thus the `using` trick described by Vittorio will do the trick.

Comment: In fact we have used this technique to port the InnCabs benchmark suite to HPX (see https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/inncabs/blob/master/include/inncabs.h#L63-L91)